# $f$ is injective and $f(U) \subset f(V)$ then $U \subset V$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I wonder the question

If $f$ is injective and $f(U) \subset f(V)$ then can I conclude $U \subset V$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $u \in U$, then $f(u) \in f(U)$, hence $f(u) \in f(V)$. Thus there is $v \in V$ such that $f(u)=f(v)$.  Since $f$ is injective, we get $u=v \in V.$